# How can I send an API Request directly from Controller in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, laravel-5

I am currently working on a project that implement API integration on several sites.

Now as I go along, I noticed that I was using too much AJAX Request using JQuery on my project (of which codes viewable on page source) and I wanted to limit that as much as possible.

Is there a way to send an API Request directly from any controller in Laravel 5.2 just like the code below?

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class HttpRequestController extends Controller
    {

        public function PostRequest($uri, $data) {

            //functional code that will post the given data to the specified uri 

        }

        public function GetRequest($uri) {

            //functional code that will retrieve the given data via the specified uri 

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Guzzle` https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle library to make HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll look into that in a blow by blow account.